# DNS issue that affects specific devices in home network with specific websites

Tags: networking, dns, home-networking

*I asked this question in Network Engineering, but was told I should post it here because home networking is outside of Network Engineering topics.*

---

I'm unable to connect to some websites, but this only happens with two devices in my home network, all the other devices are able to connect to those websites just fine.

Some of the unreachable websites: github, quora, stackexchange, bitly.

The two devices that were having this problem: Lenovo laptop with Fedora, and Raspberry Pi with Manjaro.

What I don't understand is why this problem only happened with two devices, when every other device is connected to the same router, and why does this problem only affects some specific websites and not others. On top of that, another weird thing is that this problem goes away sometimes on it's own for a few minutes, only to return again, so I would sometimes be able to connect to github, and then if I refresh the page I would lose the connection and return to the same error after a few minutes of loading: DNS address could not be found. Diagnosing the problem. DNS_PROBE_POSSIBLE.

In the end, the problem was resolved on both devices by setting the DNS server address to 1.1.1.1, but I would like someone to explain why this even happened.

Comment: Try returning the DNS server on these devices to its previous value (which was probably none, to use the ISP's), to see if the error is consistent.

Comment: It's consistent. When I return to the default DNS server (from DHCP) the problem returns on both devices.

Answer (score 0):

The DNS problem is caused by your ISP, as you have proved consistently
by repeatedly passing from one to the other.

You have no way of fixing the problem on your side, you may only complain
about the problem to the ISP's Support, without knowing if the problem
is caused by incompetence or on purpose. It would be interesting
to know what would be their answer.

In the meantime, you have an easy workaround, by using a third-party DNS
server. You may set the DNS server in your router (if supported) so
it serves the entire local network, or in each device separately.

Answer (score 0):

I had a issue that only a prat of devices had a such error, e.g. all devices are ok and TV only lost access to internet(dns), or two phones connected to wifi had access two lost it. The same time tried to connect ISP dynamic IP connection over cable to my PC and everything was OK. had to change 1.1.1.1 8.8.8.8